# Reduced Row Echelon form without scalar multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is it possible to transform any matrix to row reduced echelon form without using the row operation that multiplies a row by a scalar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. In the case of square matrices, all the other row operations either leave the determinant unchanged or negates it. So if the original matrix has determinant $\notin\{-1,0,1\}$, then its reduced row echelon form is the identity matrix (with determinant $1$) but cannot be reached using the other row operations.

Comment: Thanks! If I changed the question a bit, how could you prove that it is possible to get to row echelon form ( not row reduced) without scaling row operations?

Comment: @user3672888: Different texts seem to differ about whether (non-reduced) row echelon form requires the pivot elements to be 1 or not. If it does, then the same argument as here applies (with "triangular matrix with ones on the diagonal" instead of the identity). If not, then the usual Gaussian reduction will work -- just skip the pivot normalization steps.